# How many postions are there?

Tags: algorithm

I was practising the algorithm based programming problem.I am having difficulty,in solving this problem.I want idea (only small approach/hint)to solve this problm efficienty,so plz help me.!
Here Is the problem Statement::

Suppose there are two rabbits,named rabbit foo and rabbit bar.Initially both of them are located  at the origin(center) facing each others.

Foo knows jump of only two lengths m,n.That is foo can jump either m length  to his left or m length to his right or n length to his left or n length to his
right side in a single attempt.

Similarly bar also knows jump of only two lengths-p,q.That is bar can jump either p length  to his left or p length to his right or q length to his left or q length to his
right side in a single attempt.

Now the master of these two rabbits want to place himself exactly at one point such that both of the rabbits will be able to reach his master in one or more attempts.
Also ,the master place himself at most L lengths  away from the origin.
We have to calculate  At how many position the master can place himself.

m,n,p,q and L are very large ,as larger as 10^17.

So how to solve it efficiently.

Example::

m=1 n=2

m=4 n=5

L=1

answer=3;

As

Foo can jumps 2 length to his right side and after that one length to his left side.

Bar can jumps 5 lengths to his rgt and after that four lenth to his left side.

to reach his master who is place 1 units away from the origin.

Foo 2 length left and after that one length right side.
Bar 5 length left and 5 length rgt  to reach his master who located himself at 1 length away from origin

Master can also place himself at the origin since both foo and bar would be able to reach his master in two moves
so total positions=3.

Other Examples::

m=2 n=4

p=3 q=6

L=7

answer=3.

m=10 n=12

p=3 q=9

answer=5

Comment: When you get a solution which works for you, you're supposed to mark it as the accepted answer, so that future readers know which answer worked for you. You don't seem to realize this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Foo can reach any position that is a multiple of `gcd(m,n)` and only those. Bar can reach the positions that are multiples of `gcd(p,q)`, so the positions reachable by both are exactly the multiples of `lcm(gcd(m,n),gcd(p,q))`.

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer:Thanks!But how to use 'L' for solving this.So what will be the exact solution.Can you plz help me?

Comment: @Jack - '(only small approach/hint)' does not include the exact solution :P

Comment: @Jack: "I want idea (only small approach/hint)" that would be too big of a hint. =) This answer basically solves the problem for you.

Comment: Well thanks every one,but well at least a hint how to connect L with Daniel Fischer Solution.

Comment: @Jack how many multiples of 3 are at most `L` units away from the origin?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer::"how many multiples of 3 are at most L units away from the origin? " -Sorry sir,i didn;t get it.

Comment: If you know how to calculate that, and also for multiples of 20, say, you know how to calculate the solution to your problem (because then you know how to calculate the number in the generic case).

Comment: I don't think its giving correct answer.Lets take first cases :positions reachable by both are exactly the multiples of LCM(gcd(1,2),gcd(4,5))=LCM(1,1)=1 .But answer is 3.Similarly lets take second case :positions reachable by both are exactly the multiples of LCM(gcd(2,4),gcd(3,6))=LCM(2,3)=6.The multiples of 6 are 1,2,3,6 so total pos=4 but answer is 3.??

Comment: 1,2 and 3 are not _multiples_ of 6, but divisors. The only multiple of 6 that is `> 0` and `<= 7` is 6. The three positions in that case are `-6, 0, 6`. See something?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9613/discussion-between-jack-and-daniel-fischer)

Answer (score 1):

If **m** = LCM of ( HCF(**a**, **b**) and HCF(**c**, **d**) )
then the answer will be = 2 * [ **k** / **m** ] + 1

Basically, the shortest distance person **A** can move is HCF(**a**, **b**), similarly with person **B**.

The smallest position (nearest to 0) both **A** & **B** can be in, is `LCM` of both the `HCF`s. And +1 is for the center. You need to find the number of multiples of that `LCM` within the range **k** on both sides.

So you divide **k** by **m** and double the integral part of the division (for both sides of 0) and add 1 (for center). Hope that helps.