# Program exceeds a time limit, which seems impossible - buggy code

Tags: c++, performance, debugging, infinite-loop

This is related to maths but I'm posting my code here since there seems to be bug which eludes me.

**The question**:

> Two robots **A** & **B** are standing on position `0` located on an infinitely long straight line. Robot **A** can move towards his left or right by **a** or **b** units, and robot **B** can also do the same, but by **c** or **d** units. They are to press a button which lies on that straight line, at a distance of not more than **k** units from `0`. On how many positions *p<sub>i</sub>* can you place the button so that both the robots are able to press it (reach it actually), independent of each other. So the inputs are 5 positive integers in 1 line: **a**, **b**, **c**, **d**, **k**.
>
> Constraints: **0** ≤ **a,b,c,d,k** ≤ **10<sup>18</sup>** and number of test cases **t** where **1** ≤ **t** ≤ **1000**.
>
> Time limit: **1 sec**
>
> E.g.: Robot **A** (**a** = 1, **b** = 2), Robot **B** (**c** = 4, **d** = 5), Range: **k** = 1
>
> The answer in this case is **3**.

I suppose an explanation will make this question unnecessarily long and deviate from the main concern. I'm giving the solution I figured out and moving on to my code.

My solution:

Let **m** = LCM ( HCF(**a**, **b**) , HCF(**c**, **d**) )

The answer = 2 * [**k** / **m**] + 1

[ ] denotes the greatest integer function (just to avoid confusion).

On a short note (for those who are interested in the question), all I've done is check how many multiples of **m** exist within the range of **k** on either sides, plus the **0** position. `HCF(a,b)` will give the shortest step the robot can take, and `LCM` of both `HCF`s will give the smallest common position they can stand on. Then find the no. of multiples.

Code (C++):

```
  1 #include <cstdio>
  3 using namespace std;
  4 typedef long long LL;
  5 
  6 inline void swap(LL *a, LL *b)
  7 {
  8     *a ^= *b;
  9     *b ^= *a;
 10     *a ^= *b;
 11 }
 12 
 13 long hcf(LL a, LL b)
 14 { return !a || !b ? a+b : hcf(b,a%b); }
 15 
 16 LL lcm(LL a, LL b)
 17 {
 18     if(a < b) swap(&a,&b);
 19     LL i=a;
 20     while(a%b) a+=i;
 21     return a;
 22 }
 23 
 24 int main()
 25 {
 26     int t; scanf("%d\n",&t);
 27     while(t--)
 28     {
 29         LL a,b,c,d,k;
 30         scanf("%lld %lld %lld %lld %lld",&a,&b,&c,&d,&k);
 31         printf("%lld\n", 1 + ((k / (lcm(hcf(a,b), hcf(c,d))) ) << 1) );
 32     }
 33     return 0;
 34 }
```

I've simply implemented my answer. I also executed my program through 1000 test cases, each consisting of random +integers in the range [10<sup>16</sup>, 10<sup>18</sup>]. I did this multiple times and the worst case time consumption was **0.01** sec.

Now when I submit this code to the contest page, I get a `Time Limit Exceeded` error! This is impossible unless some buggy loop is running endlessly for a particular input. I thought I should take the experts' opinion on why is my code getting timed out. Please help

P.S.: If you have a better answer to the question, your welcome :-)

**Edit**: P.S.: I was suspicious about the way I handled large integers in `C++`, so I did a conversion to `python` and submitted that too, which again yielded a `Time Limit Exceeded` error.

Comment: What is your question for Stack Overflow?

Comment: Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982301/how-many-postions-are-there). Do you know [Jack](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1134599/jack)?

Comment: The question is, why does the code get a Time Limit Exceeded error, in other words how does it exceed 1 second on being tested by the contest site? The solution is pretty simplistic.

Comment: Do not XOR-swap. This line return !a || !b ? a+b : hcf(b,a%b); is syntactically ambiguous and may very well be interpreted (!a) || (!b ? a+b : hfcf(b,a%)) which I gather is not your intention. The swap function should be prototyped as void swap(LL& a, LL& b) and then you don't need to pass the address as a parameter. Use of such long expressions in scanf and printf make the code harder to read. Do you have any guarantee that scanf is taking the input in the contest properly? That it's not, perhaps, argc/argv[]?

Comment: Well no, I don't! Our questions are similar, but he wants to know how to solve it. I've already solved it, I'm facing a different problem here

Comment: and @dasblinkenlight there are many people out there asking for solutions to questions in a contest. So you shouldn't get all suspicious!

Comment: @Rushil any response to my comment? I'll be heading out soon.

Comment: OrgnlDave - I've used that same hcf function many times, and also, I've tried & verified my solution on a variety of test cases, so that can't be the problem. scanf() is taking input correctly, since I've submitted code to many other problems as well. In addition, I'm taking input in the same way the server will take (from input files using i/o redirector). So that's certainly not a problem

Answer (score 0):

Your code is full of `scanf` calls that read from `stdin`. It'll hang indefinitely unless the input is provided. Most contests do not have your code read from `stdin`. What do the rules say is the source of input?

Comment: The input is given from input files using i/o redirectors. I've tried my code against input in the exact same way.

Comment: Input files are provided by them. We aren't given access to those files.

Comment: I made a python program to generate an input file. Let me upload it somewhere, I'll post the link here

Comment: OK, if your input file doesn't match the exact format as theirs, that'll explain the hang.

Answer (score 0):

Take note that this code is very dangerous:

```
inline void swap(LL *a, LL *b)
{
   /* sometimes also written as *a^=*b^=*a^=*b;  */
    *a ^= *b;
    *b ^= *a;
    *a ^= *b;
}
```

If `a` and `b` are ever pointing to the same memory, this will Zero-out that memory.

(try reversing a string with an odd-number of letters by using this swap)

```
char* input = "abcde"
for(i=0, j=4; i<3; ++i, --j)
{
    swap(input+i, input+j);
}
// Result:  "ed0ba".
// With a normal-swap, 'c' would get swapped with 'c', returning "edcba"
```

Comment: Are you saying that a and b could be "same numbers"? That will surely 0 them out, but here, if a & b will be swapped only if a < b.

Comment: In this particular code, you are protected by "if (a<b)...".
But if you ever change that... or forget about that requirement and use your swap function somewhere else, it is dangerous, and you could quickly run into trouble.

Comment: Yeah! I'm always careful about that now. Had a problem in the past once.

Comment: Its a horrible way to swap variables.  It introduces risk, and doesn't improve speed.  There is no good reason to swap like this.